# What is the WCF equivalent of HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl?

Tags: wcf, url-rewriting, httpcontext, operationcontext, weboperationcontext

I've got some RESTful services running in a pure WCF context (i.e. ASP.NET compatibility is not enabled, and thus there is no `HttpContext.Current` object available).

The URLs to the services are rewritten at the start of the request using an `IHttpModule` (which at that point does have an `HttpContext` and rewrites it using `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath`) to get rid of things like the `.svc` extension from the URL.

However, I need to access the original URL that was requested from within the WCF infrastructure. Is there an equivalent to `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` on the `OperationContext` or `WebOperationContext` classes anywhere? Using `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri` returns the rewritten URL not the original one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can get the endpoint currently targeted and the Uri for it by doing:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To
```

which I think is the same thing as:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To
```

This is a `System.Uri` object, and I believe you can just get the `OriginalString` or `PathAndQuery`, or whatever parts you want from it.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

Comment: Good answer according to the title of question (saying with google search perspective)

Comment: i tried System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri, OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To, and OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To, the only one that works is OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To
```

works *most* of the time, but did not for my application. It is behind an NLB (Network Load Balancer), which causes it to lose the original input host name. *But* the input host is still in a header named "Host", which was surprisingly hard to get at. It is located at:

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Host"]
```

(the header objects at **System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders** did not truly have all the headers from the client)

Comment: Good point. Also note this problem with `UserHostAddress`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/650357/266535