# HttpRequestBase.UserHostAddress throwing error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httprequest

I am capturing some of the information on users that visit a particular section of my website and I am getting an odd error. I have a section of code that does the following.

```
string userIp = request.UserHostAddress;
```

The request variable is a HttpRequestBase. At times this works just fine and I get the IP - other times it throws an error that I am not sure how to safeguard against. This is from my error log.

"Value does not fall within the expected range.   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)"

It seems that the first time I go to a page it works just fine, the error gets thrown if I do a refresh, or go quickly to another page that capturs the same variable.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650357/httprequest-servervariables-throws-argumentexception-in-wcf-with-iis7

Comment: I read that one before I posted. That does not apply here. I am not setting the contract to OneWay.

Comment: can you try 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress' - just in case that HttpRequestBase doestn't go through same steps as HttpRequest

Comment: I gave that a try, and still get the same errors.

Answer (score 11):

I had this exact issue with my logger. I'm using dependency injection, as I suspect you are.

In my case, I was getting this error because I wasn't binding my logger to the request scope. So, it was living between requests and maintaining some of the `HttpContext` properties but throwing exceptions on the ones talking to IIS.

Since I'm using Ninject, this was simply a matter of adding the `InRequestScope()` method, from the `Ninject.Web.Common` namespace, to my binding.

**In short**: this exception seems to be thrown for a stale instance of `HttpContext` when certain properties, that are marshalled to IIS and for which the request is no longer valid, are accessed.

Hope that helps!

p.s. NLog is better than any logger you'll write. Or, if you just want exceptions, drop in ELMAH.

Comment: I got this error from a somewhat different situation. In an ASMX webservice, I had some finishing work, potentially long-running, and I wanted to do it without slowing down the main operation. So I ran it with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Since the finishing work required some access to HttpContext, I foolishly set HttpContext.Current from the lambda that started the Task. Crash when it tried to access ServerVariables.

Comment: Same issue, same solution.  I was wrapping the httpcontext to inject it and didn't set it's lifetime scope.

Note:  Also the calling services have to be lifetime scope.