# How to detect that IsOneWay is set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

As a follow up to the below question, I'm getting the same error. I would like to detect that I'm in one of these situations, and then avoid access to the servervariables collection. Right now I've got the code in a try catch - but there has to be a better way to do it.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
public void someFunction()
{
}
```

Some code that is called:

```
    protected string GetWebClientIpAddress(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
                ? context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
                : null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                    return addresses[0];
            }
            return context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("REMOTE_ADDR") ? context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : null;
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error getting request remote IP", ee);
            return "Error getting remote ip: " + ee.Message;
        }
    }
```

Original Question: 
[HttpRequest.ServerVariables throws ArgumentException in WCF with IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650357/httprequest-servervariables-throws-argumentexception-in-wcf-with-iis7)

Comment: Maybe you can just use WCF way to obtain IP address? OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]

Comment: yeah, i could, but this is logging code that is designed to record evidence of the raw request in case of a crash. I wanted it to be generic based on the request object.