# find out which URI was used to call me?

Tags: wcf

Inside a WCF service, can I find out which URI was used to call me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can e.g. look at:

```
string localAddress = OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Basically, on the server side, you'll probably only be able to determine which of the **server's** endpoints was hit - you most likely won't be able to really find out what the caller on the client used as a URL (just a hunch).

Marc

Answer (score 0):

There is [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444010/what-is-the-wcf-equivalent-of-httpcontext-current-request-rawurl) that might answer your question.

The `OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress` will not work in a service that is hosted in IIS which have multi websites. Using `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To` is more logical.